# How to show result of a async promise function in Angular2 template?

Tags: angular, typescript

The pseudo code I'm looking for is like following but it cause my browser to hang.

index.ts

```
findCustomerById(id) {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("hi");
    });
}

getCustomerNameById(id: string) {
    return this.findCustomerById(id);
    //findCustomerById returns NEW Promise<string>
}
```

index.html

```
<p>Customer: {{ getCustomerNameById('1') | async }} </p>
//this does not show anything

<p>Customer: {{ getCustomerNameById('1') | async | json }} </p>
//this shows null

<p>Customer: {{ getCustomerNameById('1') | json }}</p>
//this shows the following
{
  "__zone_symbol__state": true,
  "__zone_symbol__value": "hi"
}
```

Here is Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/pAKtCZo0Uog2GFzlj50c

Comment: Your code should work fine. If it doesn't please add the code for `puchServe.findCustomerById()`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have added `findCustomerById`

Comment: Does the browser console show any error?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer no, the browser doesn't show anything

Comment: Please try adding `<div>{{getCustomerNameById('1') | async | json}}</div>` and post if, and when yes, what it shows. And perhaps also ``<div>{{getCustomerNameById('1') | json}}</div>``

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It shown `null`

Comment: This means that `findCustomerById(id)` does return a `null`

Comment: See my previous comment

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer As you can see `findCustomerById` doesn't return null, please check `getCustomerNameById('1') | json`

Comment: We would need to see more code about how you obtain the value (Promise). Looks like a missing `then(...)` or similar.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the code is exactly what is posted in question with no changes

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I simply return a new instance of `Promise` just like above with no then and catch implemention.

Comment: I don't believe it. Please show the code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Your browser would hang if you uncomment the first template. Here you are https://plnkr.co/edit/FeVMGcW1kZdrPjiNSfmc

Comment: I think `getCustomerNameById('1') | async` calls `getCustomerNameById()` repeatedly and even hangs my browser. I think it would be better to assign the result of `getCustomerById()` (Promise or the actual value) to a property and bind to that property instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
pipes: [...],
directives: [...],
```

from `@Component()`

and add  `imports: [BrowserModule]` to `AppModule`'s `@NgModule()`

**update**

`getCustomerNameById('1') | async` calls `getCustomerNameById()` repeatedly and even hangs my browser.
It would be better to assign the result of `getCustomerById()` (Promise or the actual value) to a property and bind to that property instead.

Binding to methods that return a new value every time they are called is in general a bad idea in Angular2.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/WcABGXLqQqf177KnL2XQ?p=preview)

Comment: This didn't help, it's same as before

Comment: Actually I can't bind to a property since the parameters that are took by pseudo function `getCustomerNameById` varies.

Comment: Then call `findCustomerById` when `id` changes

Comment: I guess you misunderstood, it's not all about `id` but a few more parameters. Please suggest a way to stay with function call in template

Comment: No matter what, you won't come far with Angular2 this way. Angular change detection calls a bound method every time change detection runs. If you want more concrete feedback to your case, please provide more details.

Comment: Ah..okay thanks, I might do a few more research on topic before accept this

Comment: Sure, no worries.

Comment: What you can do is to cache the `Promise` for specific `id` values and return the same `Promise` instance. This way Angular change detection won't run amok.